# How do I get the URL back from a php database post?

Tags: php, ios, nsurl

I have an iOS app that posts an image to a php page which saves it to a database.

The iOS code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData filename:(NSString *)filename{

    NSLog(@"uploading");

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.myserver.com/appsapce/assets/uploadPics.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Set the filename
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //append the image data
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"returningOKString");

    return ([returnString isEqualToString:@"OK"]);
}
```

and the php looks like this:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

How do I return the server URL for the posted photo to my iOS app?

Thx

Comment: Why do not return the url instead of simple return "OK"? And then capture the request in your iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo "OK";` use `echo $uploadfile;`

Also I see you are passing file name from iOS only `basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`

As you know file name in iOS, just check for returnString. If its `OK`, means path is as below.

www.xyz.com/photos/fileNameIPassed

Here `fileNameIPassed = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`